# what does 'safely' mean in an ActiveRecord exception? ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: [safely] SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

I am using sqlite3 in production with rails 6 and I am getting the following error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: [safely] SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked`

I can see the error in Rollbar but I don't see it in log/production.log.

What does `[safely]` mean in this context? Does it mean rails managed to deal with this error (possibly via database timeout) without the user noticing?

Why is it that I see this error in Rollbar but not in the log file?

I tried searching online for an explanation and grepping inside rails code, but to no avail - no explanation of 'safely' that I could find.

Comment: `database is locked` means you have `rails c` or `rails s` running in a terminal.

Comment: DO NOT USE `sqlite` in production. Ever. postgresql or mysql exist for that

Answer (score 0):

Caught this error message after the very first test going through Agile Rails 6, all the advices I was able to find here (increasing timeout to 5000, using *console -s* command etc) were useless

But I was goint through this book for the 2nd time after a break and got an old app (created in Ruby 2.6.6) to compare, all the tests passed here despite using same database gems and configs, so i found the only difference between them

So, go to **test\test_helper.rb** and comment the string starts with "parallelize"

```
# parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors, with: :threads)
```

Hope it helps, but yep, maybe choosing another db is best option